# What’s the purpose of mmap memory protection PROT_NONE

Tags: linux, memory, mapping, mmap

I was reading the [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) of `mmap` and fell upon this line:

> **PROT_NONE** Pages may not be accessed.

Is there any use to map a file to memory but never access it?

Comment: [For freaking out computer scientists.](http://xkcd.com/207/)

Comment: Guard pages for buffer overflows [ref: glibc](http://mahaveerdarade.wordpress.com/tag/glibc-prot_none-pmap/)

Comment: Also for reserving (a block of) address space.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`PROT_NONE` can be used to implement [guard pages](https://www.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/coding-practices/guard-pages), Microsoft has the same concept ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366549(v=vs.85).aspx)).

To quote the first link:

> ... allocation of additional inaccessible memory during memory allocation
>   operations is a technique for mitigating against exploitation of heap
>   buffer overflows. These guard pages are unmapped pages placed between
>   all memory allocations of one page or larger. The guard page causes a
>   segmentation fault upon any access.

Thus useful in implementing protection for areas such as network interfacing, virtual machines, and interpreters.  An example usage: [pthread_attr_setguardsize,  pthread_attr_getguardsize](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_attr_getguardsize.3.html).

Answer (score 15):

PROT_NONE allocates a contiguous virtual memory region with no permissions granted.

This can be useful, as other have mentioned, to implement guards (pages that on touch cause segfaults, both for bug hunting and security purposes) or "magic" pointers where values within a PROT_NONE mapping are to be interpreted as something other than a pointer.

Another use is when an application wishes to map multiple independent mappings as a *virtually contiguous* mapping. This would be done by first mmapping a large enough chunk with PROT_NONE, and then performing other mmap calls with the MAP_FIXED flag and an address set within the region of the PROT_NONE mapping (the use of MAP_FIXED automatically unmaps part of mappings that are being "overridden").

Answer (score 8):

One possible application: you can use it to reserve a memory range. After allocating such a region, you can use pointers into that range as *special* values.

One possible application would be a library which transparently switches between “small” and “big” integers, with a form of small value optimization. A big integer would be represented as a pointer to a memory region holding the actual number. A small integer would be a pointer pointing into this reserved memory area, representing the number equal to the offset into that area. (I'm not saying that this is the best method to implement such a library, only that it should be possible.)

Comment: The Java VM does that to reduce the amount of memory required for pointers.